How to detect if user navigate back (mobile) in Javascript?
I have a simple HTML file that has a javascript code:
<p>Press The Back Button and see a message!</p>

<script>
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    alert("location: " + document.location);
}
</script>

I'm using Android 11 with the latest version of Google Chrome, when I press the back button, I want to show an alert with the location.

How I can do this? Why my code is not working?

the onpopstate event is only triggered when the navigation history changes and your current code does not change the history state.
By pushing a state onto the history stack immediately, using window.history.pushState(), the onpopstate event can be triggered when the Back button is pressed:
<script>
window.history.pushState({page: 1}, "", "#nogo");
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    alert("location: " + document.location);
}
</script>

When the back button is clicked, it will change the history state, which triggers the onpopstate event.
Note: #nogo in the state is used to prevent the page from scrolling when a new history state is added.

<script>
    function pushHistoryState() {
        window.history.pushState({ page: 1 }, "title 1", "#state1");
    }

    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        alert("Current location: " + document.location);
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        pushHistoryState();
    };
</script>

you can handle the back button and showing an alert with the location can be achieved using the window.onpopstate event correctly.
window.onpopstate only gets triggered when the active history entry changes. Simply pressing the back button won't trigger this event unless you have manipulated the history stack using history.pushState() or history.replaceState().
Try this code. Hope this code will help your problem. If you have any problem, feel free to reach out me.
